# Geoserver on GCP https

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, geoserver, wms

I installed GeoServer with tomcat on a ubuntu VM on Google Cloud Platform. It was working fine till I got an SSL certificate for the website. When the website runs on HTTPS, the wms links from Geoserver do not work. I get this error in the console.

`net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I tried adding the proxy base URL, but that changes nothing. How can I get these WMS links to work with HTTPS?

Comment: what did you put in the proxy? what request are you making? what does the log file say?

Comment: I'm making a WMS request, and I am using https://example.com/geoserver as the base proxy.   Just checked the log file, couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) tutorial from the tomcat documentation worked. I reinstalled tomcat and imported the certificates from the GCP. And now, the wms links work but with a privacy warning (I guess that's something to do with how I imported the certificates.).